# Symfony2: Updating entities after changing the tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on a project. I am using symfony2 with xampp with PHP version of 5.5.19 . Everything works fine , until I realize that I need to change my database tables so it will be normalize. And so, I do it but then when I update the entities it works fine . But then I am also using FOSUserBundle.

I have two bundles :

```
MatrixBundle
UserBundle
```

MatrixBundle is already updated since it came from my database  but I have difficulty on how I can I update the UserBundle since it is extending the FOSUserBundle . How can I do it? Do I still need to update it?

This are the things I tried ,when I update my bundles :

> 1. I change the database configuration since I also renamed my database
> 2. I run this in cmd php app/console doctrine:mapping:import
>      --force MatrixBundle xml ,both of the bundle
> 3. php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MatrixBundle

After doing this , I clear my cache ,then I tried to run my application  it gives me this error .

```
Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
```

What could be the problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you update the database schema `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: what's the use of updating the schema? sorry I am just new to this :)

Comment: any comments or answer?